# angular 2 Ahead-Of-Time compilation with @ngtools/webpack, how to?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-aot

I want to compile angular templates in webpack but it does not fully work.

This is my webpack.config.js

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='Watch - Development' />
var AotPlugin = require("@ngtools/webpack").AotPlugin;

var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var basePath = path.join(__dirname, "wwwroot");

module.exports = {
    context: basePath,
    entry: {
        main: ["./app/main.ts"],
        productModule: "./app/components/product-module",
        adminModule: "./app/components/admin-module" 
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "wwwroot/built"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "built/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "html-loader",
                query: {
                    minimize: true,
                    ignoreCustomFragments: [/\{\{.*?}}/],
                    removeAttributeQuotes: false,
                    caseSensitive: true,
                    customAttrSurround: [ [/#/, /(?:)/], [/\*/, /(?:)/], [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/] ],
                    customAttrAssign: [ /\)?\]?=/ ] ,
                    root: basePath,
                    attrs: false // ['img:src', 'link:href']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "@ngtools/webpack"
            }//,
           // { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader?root=." }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    },
    devtool: false,
    plugins: [
        new AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.json",
            basePath: basePath
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            //filename: "[name].c.bundle.js"//, 
            names: ["main"]
        })
        , new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            minimize: true,
            acorn: true,
            angular: true,
            beautify: false,
            compress: {
                properties: true,
                sequences: true,
                dead_code: true,
                drop_debugger: true,
                unsafe_comps: true,
                conditionals: true,
                comparisons: true,
                evaluate: true,
                booleans: true,
                keep_fargs: false,
                loops: true,
                unsafe: true,
                angular: true,
                unused: true,
                cascade: true,
                hoist_funs: true,
                join_vars: true,
                warnings: false
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            }
        })
    ]

};
```

and my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "diagnostics": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "include": [ "typings" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/module#AppModule"
  }
}
```

When my main.ts imports @angular/platform-browser and calls platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);

```
import 'core-js';
import 'zone.js';

import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowser } from "@angular/platform-browser";
enableProdMode();
import { AppModule } from './module';
const platform = platformBrowser();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Then the size of main bundle is around 680kB but the site throws:

```
NoProviderError_nativeError: Error: No provider for CompilerFactory!
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:23:4831), <anonymous>:30:27) [<root>]
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:53:73), <anonymous>:64:16) [<root>]
    at new NoProviderError (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:53:73), <anonymous>:126:16) [<root>]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:84:73), <anonymous>:492:19) [<root>]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:84:73), <anonymous>:531:25) [<root>]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:84:73), <anonymous>:463:25) [<root>]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:84:73), <anonymous>:332:21) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:32:7749), <anonymous>:403:62) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:32:7749), <anonymous>:391:21) [<root>]
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:74:73), <anonymous>:17:10) [<root>]
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:74:73) [<root>]
    at n (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:1:101) [<root>]
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:119:29) [<root>]
    at n (http://localhost:59432/built/main.bundle.js:1:101) [<root>]constructResolvingMessage: (keys)injectors: Array[1]keys: Array[1]message: (...)name: (...)stack: (...)__proto__: AbstractProviderError
ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull @ VM1617:492
ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault @ VM1617:531
ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey @ VM1617:463
ReflectiveInjector_.get @ VM1617:332
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ VM1627:403
PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ VM1627:391
(anonymous) @ VM1271:17
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:74
n @ main.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:119
n @ main.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

But if I call platform-browser-dynamic hoping that the AotPlugin will substitute imports and calls:

```
import 'core-js';
import 'zone.js';
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
enableProdMode();
import { AppModule } from './module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Then the main.bundle.js is 1076kB which clearly indicates that the platform-browser-dynamic has not been replaced with platform-browser and the template compiler has not been removed from code tree.

What is the proper way to get rid of template compiler from bundle when using webpack (but not by using angular typescript compiler prior to running webpack)

I'll also list my package.json in case that helps:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install && gulp restore && gulp build:sass"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.7",
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.32",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "1.0.7",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-promise": "4.0.5",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "2.0.13",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "2.3.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.1.3",
    "gulp-webpack": "1.5.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rollup": "^0.36.3",
    "rxjs": "5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.52",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "2.0.13",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "2.3.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.1.3",
    "html-loader": "0.4.4",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rollup-loader": "0.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "2.7.1",
    "typescript": "2.1.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "1.0.15"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so... it's new day and having a fresh mind I decided to investigate that issue.

I went to ./node-modules/@ngtools/webpack/src and I have identified the file that is responsible for substituting the bootstraping code. It is in file loader.js.

I have added some console logs to that code:

```
console.log("searching for bootstrapModule.")
    const bootstraps = allCalls
        .filter(call => call.expression.kind == ts.SyntaxKind.PropertyAccessExpression)
        .map(call => call.expression)
        .filter(access => {
        return access.name.kind == ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier
            && access.name.text == 'bootstrapModule';
        });
    console.log("bootstraps:", bootstraps.length);

    const calls = bootstraps
        .reduce((previous, access) => {
            console.log("previous:", previous);
            console.log("access:", access);
            const expressions = refactor.findAstNodes(access, ts.SyntaxKind.CallExpression, true);
            return previous.concat(expressions);
    }, [])
        .filter((call) => {
            console.log("call:", call);

        return call.expression.kind == ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier
            && call.expression.text == 'platformBrowserDynamic';
        });
    console.log("matching calls:", calls.length);
```

The 'bootstrapModule' part was found but the 'platformBrowserDynamic' was not.
Looking at what was being parsed by the code I have identified that issue.

Basically what I had was:

```
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

While the plugin is only able to identify code in that form:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```